# Roof replacement - second opinion needed

Tags: water, repair, roof, roofing, shingles

I recently had my roof inspected and following are some of the pictures. According to the inspector, the roof has a lifetime of 6 months and has to be immediately replaced. They also mentioned that since we just had a hailstorm, we should not delay with the insurance claim.

I am new to home ownership so checking here if anyone has a second opinion. TIA.

-S

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's covered by insurance, why do you want a second opinion? Not saying you shouldn't, but trying to understand. It is an old roof, and there is clear hail damage, so it needs replacement. Having said that, how can anybody estimate the life of a roof with that level of accuracy? I've seen roofs like this last 10 more years. Or leak the next day.

Comment: I cannot tell from the pictures if the shingles are damaged more than the surface removed.  If they are cracked or have holes, then replacing soon is good.  Insurance might have a time limit also, before not paying(6 months).  If it was insurance inspector and not your own, then go for it.

Answer (score 3):

There is quite a bit of surface damage to the shingles but that's about all that can be seen from the photos. The ridge cap looks loose and the end looks like it's missing a few pieces.

You should speak with your insurance company soon and have them evaluate it as a claim since you did have the hail storm. Keep in mind that they might not (probably won't) pay the complete cost for a new roof. They would probably prorate it and many policies nowadays have higher deductibles for storm related damages.

If you're in a position to do this whether insurance covers it all  or not, You should get it done. Once they start to leak, the the cost to repair damages can skyrocket.

Comment: @FreeMan    Thanks..been a long day

Comment: The consequences of filing a claim on homeowner's insurance these days may include non-renewal of the policy. I'd like to talk with perhaps an independent adjuster or non-captive agent to get a multi-year big picture view of the consequences before contacting your insurance company.